# Dynamically increase size of list in Rcpp

Tags: r, list, rcpp

I am trying to implement a "coupling to the past" algorithm in Rcpp. For this I need to store a matrix of random numbers, and if the algorithm did not converge create a new matrix of random numbers and store that as well. This might have to be done 10+ times or something until convergence.

I was hoping I could use a `List` and dynamically update it, similar as I would in R. I was actually very surprised it worked a bit but I got errors whenever the list size becomes large. This seems to make sense as I did not allocate the needed memory for the additional list elements, although I am not that familiar with C++ and not sure if that is the problem.

Here is an example of what I tried. however be aware that **this will probably crash your R session**:

```
library("Rcpp")

cppFunction(
includes = ' 
NumericMatrix RandMat(int nrow, int ncol)
 {
  int N = nrow * ncol;
  NumericMatrix Res(nrow,ncol);
  NumericVector Rands  = runif(N);
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
  {
    Res[i] = Rands[i];
  }
  return(Res);
 }',

code = '
void foo()
{
  // This is the relevant part, I create a list then update it and print the results:
  List x;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)  
  {
   x[i] = RandMat(100,10);
   Rf_PrintValue(wrap(x[i]));
  }
}
')


foo()
```

Does anyone know a way to do this without crashing R? I guess I could initiate the list at a fixed amount of elements here, but in my application the amount of elements is random.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to "allocate" enough space for your list. Maybe you can use something like a `resize`function:

```
List resize( const List& x, int n ){
    int oldsize = x.size() ;
    List y(n) ;
    for( int i=0; i<oldsize; i++) y[i] = x[i] ;
    return y ;
}
```

and whenever you want your list to be bigger than it is now, you can do:

```
x = resize( x, n ) ;
```

Your initial list is of size 0, so it expected that you get unpredictable behavior at the first iteration of your loop.

Comment: You can also do things like `x.push_back(newElement)` with the usual caveat that it do a complete copy underneath.  These really are vectors underneath, and you *must* reserve space first. Alternatively, grow STL data types (they are better at this) and convert to R / Rcpp types before returning.

Comment: One difference between using a List or a STL collection, is that the former guarantees protection from garbage collection of its elements, the latter doesn't. Protecting each element is not feasible for large collections (RecursiveRelease speed and stack limits), please correct me if I am wrong.